# Uniform convergence of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

> **Question**: is the sequence of function $(f_n)$ defined by, $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$ for all $x\in A$ where $A$ is
>   bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, is uniformly convergent on $A$?

**My attempt**: consider

$|f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)|=|\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|= \frac{1}{(n+1)!}|x^{n+1}|$

$$<\epsilon$$ if $(n+1)!>\frac{1}{\epsilon} |x^{n+1}|$

i.e. if $(n+1)n!>\frac{1}{\epsilon} |x^{n+1}|$

i.e. if $n+1>\frac{1}{\epsilon (n!)} |x^{n+1}|$

i.e if $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon (n!)} |x^{n+1}|-1$

So let $N\text{ be an integer} ≥\frac{1}{\epsilon (n!)} |x^{n+1}|-1$ then

$|f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n≥N$

Hence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $A$.

**Is am i correct?**

Further, I am confused **why such an integer $N$ exists?** is because of $A$ is bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ hence $|x^{n+1}|$ is bounded for every $x\in A$ and hence such an integer exists! But still I have doubt on existence of $N$.

Please help...

Comment: Showing $|f_{n+1}-f_n|<\epsilon$ does not prove pointwise convergence, much less uniform convergence. However the $f_n$ do in fact converge uniformly on bounded sets.

Comment: @zhw sir, isn't we know a sequence of function $(f_n)$ defined on $E$ converges uniformly on $E$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an integer $N$ such that $m,n≥N$ and $x\in E$ implise $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|≤\epsilon$. Please help

Comment: Yes, but $|f_{n+1}-f_n|<\epsilon$ is different from that.

Comment: @zhw. Sir didn't get your last comment

Comment: As per zwh's comment, consider the harmonic series $f_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$, then $|f_{n+1}-f_n| = \frac{1}{n+1} \rightarrow 0$, but you do not have convergence.

Comment: @Dayton sir, but the result " sequence of function $(f_n)$ defined on $E$ converges uniformly on $E$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an integer $N$ such that $m,n≥N$ and $x\in E$ implise $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|≤\epsilon$ "  is from standard textbook Walter rudin. Is I applied result wrongly? where I done a mistake?

Comment: The mistake is that you checked only $m=n+1$. Whereas the definition requires one to check $m,n \geq N$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Put $M=\sup_{x\in A}|x|$. Then for every $n$, if $x\in A$ then $\frac{|x^n|}{n!}\leq \frac{M^n}{n!}$. Since the numerical series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{M^n}{n!}$ converges, it follows from [Weierstrass M test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges uniformly on the set $A$.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Sir is my approach is not correct?

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately your approach is not correct. See the comments of @zhw above.